# Is there an alternative to WHERE COUNT () with Window Function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do a grouping by two columns and filter the result only by records that don't have the first column duplicated. Then the result values could be used as KEY and VALUE, respectively.
I achieved the desired result in two different ways, but none of them seems to be adequate.

To simplify the problem, I will summarize it with a table with only two columns and few values:

```
create table example (
    foreign_key integer,
    item_value text
);

insert into example (foreign_key, item_value) values 
(1, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'a'), 
(3, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (4, 'c'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'b');
```

The first way was using CTE and `WITH` clause, then filtering with a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
with grouped AS (
    select foreign_key, item_value 
    from example 
    group by 1, 2 
    order by 1 -- ordering only to view in case of running individually.
)
select * 
from grouped g 
where (select count(foreign_key) from grouped where foreign_key = g.foreign_key) = 1;
```

The second way was using a subquery with the `OVER` window function in the `FROM` clause:

```
select foreign_key, item_value 
from (
    select *, count(foreign_key) over(partition by foreign_key) as n 
    from example 
    group by 1, 2 
) t 
where t.n = 1;
```

Both ways return the same result, correct for the inputs used:

```
foreign_key item_value
2   "a"
5   "b"
```

But they seem to be excessively expensive, besides not being so pleasant to read.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: "But they seem to be excessively expensive" - are they actually expensive? What does the execution-plan look like? Do you have the right indexes?

Comment: Why are you doing `group by 1, 2 ` ? **Edit**: Ah, I found out that it's ordinal notation: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/f0d26caea1-group-by-1-2-3-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a simple group by with counting distinct values:

```
select foreign_key, max(item_value) as item_value
from example
group by foreign_key
having count(distinct item_value) = 1
order by foreign_key;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf273375e3469b810032777cf7f8c4cd)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `exists`

```
 select distinct foreign_key,item_value
    from example e where exists (select 1 from example e1 where e.foreign_key=e1.foreign_key having count(distinct item_value)=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, count(*) over (partition by foreign_key) as cnt
      from example e
     ) e
where cnt = 1;
```

However, the aggregation method is also feasible.  It would be interesting to check which is faster.

The alternative if the rows are guaranteed to be unique would be `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from example e
where not exists (select 1
                  from example e2
                  where e2.foreign_key = e.foreign_key and e2.value <> e.value
                 );
```

Both of these methods allow you to easily return all columns in a given row.